# Сброс стиля transofrm при клике на ссылку на секцию

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот ссылка на pen проекта 
https://codepen.io/LionCane/pen/KKdmEPZ
Была задумка сделать выезжающее меню слева и сдвиг контента сайта при раскрытие этого меню. Всё работает хорошо, но при клике на ссылку, чтобы перейти в секцию, сбрасывается стиль transoform: translateX(30%) у блока content.

```
  <a href="#main" class="menu_link">Главная</a>
  <a href="#news" class="menu_link">Новости</a>
  <a href="#contacts" class="menu_link">Контакты</a>
  <a href="#portfolio" class="menu_link">Портфолио</a>
```

То есть открыв меню, нажав на ссылку происходит скролл до секции, после чего блок content становиться в обычное положение без стиля transform.

```
.content_active {
  transform: translateX(30%);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема ( preventDefault пробовал, он уберёт возможность переходить по блокам по id").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А такой вариант, вместо `transform: translateX(30%);` для `.content_active` использовать `margin-left: 30%;` для `.content_active>section`? Принцип тот же, но вопрос решается. Пример:

upd. упс, что-то я, кажется, не то сделал. Вероятно, нужно было прятать блок с меню при клике на любую ссылку?

```js
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
  $('.content').toggleClass('content_active');
})
$('.menu_link').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } 
  });
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.main {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
.news {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.contacts {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.portfolio {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.menu_active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.menu-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.menu-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.menu-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: -35px;
  top: 10px;
}
.content {
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.content>section {
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.content_active {
  /*transform: translateX(30%);*/
}
.content_active>section {
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
    <nav class="menu-list">
      <a href="#main" class="menu_link">Главная</a>
      <a href="#news" class="menu_link">Новости</a>
      <a href="#contacts" class="menu_link">Контакты</a>
      <a href="#portfolio" class="menu_link">Портфолио</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="main" id="main">
      <h2>Главная</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="news" id="news">
      <h2>Новости</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="contacts" id="contacts">
      <h2>Контакты</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
      <h2>Портфолио</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Убрать блок при клике:

```js
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
  $('.content').toggleClass('content_active');
})
$('.menu_link').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu_active');
      $('.content').removeClass('content_active');
    } 
  });
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.main {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
.news {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.contacts {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.portfolio {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.menu_active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.menu-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.menu-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.menu-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: -35px;
  top: 10px;
}
.content {
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.content>section {
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.content_active {
  transform: translateX(30%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
    <nav class="menu-list">
      <a href="#main" class="menu_link">Главная</a>
      <a href="#news" class="menu_link">Новости</a>
      <a href="#contacts" class="menu_link">Контакты</a>
      <a href="#portfolio" class="menu_link">Портфолио</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="main" id="main">
      <h2>Главная</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="news" id="news">
      <h2>Новости</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="contacts" id="contacts">
      <h2>Контакты</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
      <h2>Портфолио</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myclass.addEventListener("click", function(){
$('.content_active').attr('style', 'transform'); // Именно УДАЛИТ свойство style
});
```